# POST method returns 400 (Bad Request) in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2019

Few post methods which are invoked from Xamarin.Android retuning 400 (Bad Request) in Visual Studio 2019. It works fine in Xamarin.iOS as the web API codes are shared.

The same source code is working fine in Visual Studio 2017.

We have tried the same service from console application created in VS 2019 and it is working fine.

This is a Xamarin Native app not Forms.

Comment: Right click your android project -> **Properties** -> **Android Options** -> **Advanced** , and choose the SSL as Native TLS 1.2+ .

Comment: Tried it's not working.

Comment: Did the url has the prefix `https` ?

Comment: we have tried both https and http (prod & pre-prod) and selected Native TLS 1.2+. It's not working.

Comment: Try to create a new blank project and move the part of code to it, then check if the issue still exists .